# How to do nested jitclass array instantiation

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am attempting to use numba to speed up my code and need to use an array of a jitclass inside another jitclass. I can't seem to find a way to pass the array through to the jitclass however.

```
from numba import jitclass, int32

my_inner_spec = [
    ('a', int32)
]

@jitclass(my_inner_spec)
class MyInner:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a


my_outer_spec = [('inner', MyInner.class_type.instance_type[:])]

@jitclass(my_outer_spec)
class MyOuter:
  def __init__(self, inner):
    self.inner= inner

MyOuter([MyInner(0)])
```

This produces this error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-3f644c4985b0> in <module>()
     18     self.inner= inner
     19 
---> 20 MyOuter([MyInner(0)])

...
...

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0x7fbdde552550>.
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Cannot cast reflected list(instance.jitclass.MyInner#7fbdde6c8650<a:int32>) to array(instance.jitclass.MyInner#7fbdde6c8650<a:int32>, 1d, A): %".19" = load {i8*, i8*}, {i8*, i8*}* %"inner"

File "<ipython-input-106-3f644c4985b0>", line 18:
  def __init__(self, inner):
    self.inner= inner
    ^

[1] During: lowering "(self).inner = inner" at <ipython-input-106-3f644c4985b0> (18)
[2] During: resolving callee type: jitclass.MyOuter#7fbdde6c8810<inner:array(instance.jitclass.MyInner#7fbdde6c8650<a:int32>, 1d, A)>
[3] During: typing of call at <string> (3)

Enable logging at debug level for details.

File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list) say, typed.List is an experimental feature, and it seems that inferring the type from a normal Python list doesn't work.

The following is a bit more verbose, but it works:

```
my_outer_spec = [('inner', nb.types.ListType(MyInner.class_type.instance_type))]

@nb.experimental.jitclass(my_outer_spec)
class MyOuter:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

lst = nb.typed.List()
lst.append(MyInner(0))
MyOuter(lst)
```